# Написать spec для сборки rpm?

Tags: centos, rpm

Есть проект (код на python).

При сборке rpm в нем нужно:

- изменить файл А (диффы имеются)
- добавить файл Б

Как это описать в spec-файле?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью патча (патчей):

```
Summary         : Some package to be packed
Name            : some_package
Version         : 1.0
Release         : 1
License         : BSD
Vendor          : user241542
Packager        : user241542
Group           : Development/Libraries
URL             : http://www.ru.stackoverflow.com
Source          : some_package.tar.gz
Patch0          : some_package.patch
BuildRoot       : %{_tmppath}/%{name}

%Description
The %name package contains library or utility.

%Prep
%setup -q -n %{name}
%patch0 -p1
```

По большому счёту можно добавить и какие-то произвольные действия в пункте `%prep` - `cp`, `mv`, исполнение скрипта.